# How to insert a ca-cert inside a container through oc edit deploy <pod/container_name>

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I'm trying to make an ssl based connection to memsql from an openshift pod/container. I have to insert an self-signed ca-certificate inside the pod such that the connection is established between memsql and the pod. I have following ideas but not sure how to implement them:
1. Mount a path in volumeMounts: like /etc/ssl/certs and insert the certificate in that path and give a secret for that file name, but how do I copy that file to the specified path.
2. Copy the contents of the certificate in the deployment config under secrets, but will it be validated and how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create TLS secret:

```
oc create secret tls mycert --cert /tmp/cert.pem --key /tmp/key.pem
```

Then mount this secret into your container into /certs directory

```
oc set volume dc/myapp --add -t secret -m /certs --name cert --secret-name mycert
```

You cert will be available inside pod at **/certs/tls.crt** and key will be at **/certs/tls.key**

Comment: These certificates which you've asked to add are client certificate, but I want to add root Certificate(caCert) and update the ca-bundle.crt in the container with the root Certificate. Can you help with that part.

Comment: you generally should do that as part of your Docker image

Comment: How can I give the path of the cert file from my local machine to the dockerFile or docker container.

Comment: just add needed certs to docker image, that's how it's done mostly. Every time you add new cert - you rebuild the image, upload to registry and restart pod from new image. You may also automate that using Jenkins jobs.

Comment: I'm new to creating Docker Image and confused on how to add the certs file which is part of my local machine in the DockerFile so that it becomes part of the image and container so on....

Comment: @ Vasili Angapov what is dc/myapp in below command oc set volume dc/myapp --add -t secret -m /certs --name cert --secret-name mycert